# Simple XML namespace - Display data in the table php

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

On the local server is api to send me information in xml format. Using Curl Simple XML and I managed to put them in the variable and to echo in raw format. But i want to echo data in table using php.

```
<?php
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, Array(
                CURLOPT_PORT => "8080",
                CURLOPT_URL => "http://10.10.10.91:8080/StanjeKupca/services/Service.ServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint/getPartner?sifPar=1000001",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "utf8",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "cache-control: no-cache",
                )
            ));
            $data = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            $xml = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
            // die('<pre>' . print_r($xml], TRUE) . '</pre>');

            foreach ($xml->ns:return as $item) {
                echo $item->ax21:kolicina;
                echo $item->ax21:nazPar;
                echo $item->ax21:sifPar;
            } 

        ?>
```

After echo $data this is what i get in raw format.

```
<ns:getPartnerResponse xmlns:ns="http://mis.com" xmlns:ax21="http://bean/xsd">
<ns:return type="bean.PartnerBean">
    <ax21:idPosPar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true" />
    <ax21:kolicina>70.0</ax21:kolicina>
    <ax21:nazPar>SOMEDATA</ax21:nazPar>
    <ax21:sifPar>1000001</ax21:sifPar>
</ns:return>
```

I don't know to deal with namespaces!!

Comment: This is one of those questions for which the answer is, "Write the code to do it." [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) may be a good place to start.

Comment: Hello @ElliotteRustyHarold take a look, now i add more details about my problem. Thanks!